# Has there ever been some Doctor Who story in which multiple companions from different Doctors were kidnapped?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel, tardis

I mean have there ever been some book, audio, comic storyline, or even tv episode, that we are greeted with The Doctor, and he must go save his previous companions from regenerations past. This isn’t referring to the special episode in Sarah Jane Adventures where Matt Smith appears though.

Comment: Are you actually recalling such an episode, or is there anything else to make you think there was?

Comment: I recall a comic book where multiple companions from different Doctor's were kidnapped, and all put together as a trap for the Doctor. And all the Doctors met up when rescuing them, maybe it was the Master who did the kidnapping, I can't recall.

Comment: I was just wondering if this happened because I would love to read/listen/watch this. How would these companions react to a different man calling himself the Doctor? How would the Doctor  presumably  React to seeing future companions

Comment: Sorry I can't add more, it was so long ago and I don't have it any more. I cant even remember if it was IDW or Titan or another publisher.

Comment: @JamesfromNZ I think the comic you're thinking of is IDW's 12-part 50th anniversary series _Prisoners of Time_. It was actually Adam Mitchell who did the kidnapping, after teaming up with the Master for revenge on the Doctor.

Comment: Adam? Is that the same guy The Doctor abandoned for getting the brain info download modification?

Answer (score 8):

This basically happens in "[The Five Doctors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Five_Doctors)," the twentieth anniversary show.  The First, Second, Third, and Fifth Doctors all make major appearances, along with quite a few companions.  Susan, the Brigadier, and Sarah Jane Smith have substantial roles, along with the then-current companions Tegan and Turlough.  Jamie, Zoe, and Liz also appear as projections to throw the Doctors off the trail as they all play the Game of Rassilon.  (Jamie and Zoe are recognized as fake when a later Doctor remembers that their memories of the time they spent traveling in the TARDIS were wiped at the end of "The War Games.")

There is some swapping of companions from incarnation to incarnation as the story goes on.  Sarah Jane Smith is quite surprised to see that the Third Doctor is back when she meets him.  The First Doctor, when he reaches the TARDIS, has a brief confrontation with the Fifth Doctor's companions about just whose TARDIS it is.  It is interesting to see the Doctor's associates having to interact with different regenerations than they are familiar with.  It also continues the gag introduced in "The Three Doctors" of the various Doctors not getting along.

There is also "[The Two Doctors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Two_Doctors)," with the Second Doctor guest starring alongside the then-current Sixth.  Jamie also appears, in a major role this time.  After the Doctor and Jamie are separated early on, the Sixth Doctor eventually rescues him after Jamie has evidently spent a considerable amount of time on an abandoned space station.  This may have been done in part as a way of explaining Frazier Hines' much older appearance.  Unfortunately, while it has some interesting moments (and a higher budget than usual), the story is not very good.  It is riddled with poor costuming and continuity errors and saddled with a heavy-handed moral about how eating meat is like murder.

Comment: Yeah I’ve seen this one, and it would be so much better if Tom Baker would’ve come back for it.

Answer (score 3):

What you have described in your question and comments - wanting to see "how would these companions react to a different man calling himself the Doctor" - basically happens in any of the "multiple Doctor" TV episodes:

- The Three Doctors
- The Five Doctors
- The Two Doctors
- The Day of The Doctor

In pretty much all of these episodes we see the companions deal with seeing a different incarnation of The Doctor to the one they travel with.

From *The Two Doctors*:

> PERI: Doctor.
>   JAMIE: He's not the Doctor I know.
>   DOCTOR: I am too, Jamie McCrimmon. I am another aspect of him, just as he is of me.
>   JAMIE: Eh?
>   DOCTOR: I was him, he will be me.
>   JAMIE: Who will I be?

We also saw Sarah Jane's reaction when she realised who the Tenth Doctor was in *School Reunion*:

> DOCTOR: Hello, Sarah Jane.
>   SARAH: It's you. Oh, Doctor Oh, my God, it's you, isn't it. You've regenerated.
>   DOCTOR: Yeah. Half a dozen times since we last met.
>   SARAH: You look incredible.

The Eleventh Doctor appeared in *The Sarah Jane Adventures* episode *Death of The Doctor* in front of Sarah Jane *and* Jo Grant:

> DOCTOR: Hello, Sarah Jane.
>   SARAH JANE: Doctor.
>   RANI: That's the Doctor?
>   JO: What Doctor? The Doctor? My Doctor?
>   SARAH JANE: Yeah, well, he can change his face.
>   JO: I know, but into a baby's?

I am not familiar with *all* extended universe media, but there are *The Companion Chronicles* on Big Finish audio productions that have brought various companions together. The episode *Dumb Waiter* brings together Jamie and Leela, for example, but some of these stories do not include a portrayal of The Doctor.

Answer (score 0):

It happened in the mid-'90's *Doctor Who Magazine* comics story "Ground Zero". The villains kidnap Susan, Sarah Jane and Peri. (The main story involves the Seventh Doctor and Ace, though.)